# html2pdf and local (latvian) language characters

Tags: character-encoding, pdf-generation, html2pdf

I am using Html2PDf to convert html to pdf.

But I am not able to achieve that it shows local (latvian) language letters. It shows ? instead.

I do understand that I should somehow add appropriate fonts, but I do not know where to get those fonts (which one support latvinan language) and how to add them into html2pdf.

Html2Pdf is based on tcpdf and currently there is font folder. 
I think that is seems trivial question, but I was searching via google, but have not found answer that works for me.

```
    require_once('inc/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','en');
    //$html2pdf->pdf->setDefaultFont('times');                         
    // HEADER
    $pdf_output .='<page style="font-size: 11px; >';
    $pdf_output .= '<img src="images/raka_pdf_logo.png" alt="logo"/><br><br><br><br>';
     ...
```

Comment: If you still have that problem, post the rest of your code too. Because, its impossible to debug and only users, who have had the problem could answer. Though UTF-8 should support all characters, maybe switching the encoding type to something different might work? Though, if you use font that is very custom, then it might not work. For that try using a extremely common font, like Verdana or Arial.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the right font-family in html2pdf>tcpdf>fonts
[image]